# How do you get the key equivalent to display on an NSButton?

Tags: objective-c, nsbutton

I have the key equivalent set and no images set, but the key equivalent does not show on the NSButton.  How do I get this to display?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can on Mac. The underline on a character in the button text (showing the shortcut key) is a Windows-only thing.

Comment: Or put the label as Cmd+S, but this is not the way apple say.